# Change div content after its clicked and clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This is the jQuery code that basically opens and closes a div:

```
jQuery('#filter_werk').find('.raven-sortable').addClass('opened');

var toggle = document.getElementById('deknop');
var slider = document.querySelector('.raven-sortable');

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSlider, false);

function toggleSlider(){
    if (slider.classList.contains('opened')) {
        slider.classList.remove('opened');
        slider.classList.add('closed');
    } else {
        slider.classList.remove('closed');
        slider.classList.add('opened');
    }
}
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is change the content of the following div from "FILTER +" to "FILTER -" and back again to "FILTER +" when its clicked again

```
<div id="deknop">FILTER +</div>
```

Could this be done without breaking the current jQuery code?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood the function `toggleSlider` works fine so try:

```
function toggleSlider(){
    if (slider.classList.contains('opened')) {
        slider.classList.remove('opened');
        slider.classList.add('closed');
        toggle.innerHTML = "FILTER +";
    } else {
        slider.classList.remove('closed');
        slider.classList.add('opened');
        toggle.innerHTML = "FILTER -";
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thanks for taking the time and educating me a bit more Luis

Answer (score 0):

You can add some logic to your `toggleSlider()` function that will change your `#deknop` text based on what it currently is (either ‘FILTER +’ or ‘FILTER -‘ like this:

```
function toggleSlider(){
    $('#deknop').html($('#deknop').text() == 'FILTER +' ? 'FILTER -' : 'FILTER +');
    if (slider.classList.contains('opened')) {
        slider.classList.remove('opened');
        slider.classList.add('closed');
    } else {
        slider.classList.remove('closed');
        slider.classList.add('opened');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

if I had to do this jQuery-style, I would either way try to separate the data from the view. Something like:

```js
(() => {
  const state = {
    sliderOpen: true,
  };

  const $slider = $('.raven-sortable');
  const $toggle = $('#deknop');

  const updateView = () => {
    if (state.sliderOpen) {
      $slider.addClass('opened').removeClass('closed');
    } else {
      $slider.addClass('closed').removeClass('opened');
    }

    $toggle.text(`FILTER ${state.sliderOpen ? '+' : '-'}`);
  };

  const onToggleClick = () => {
    state.sliderOpen = !state.sliderOpen;
    updateView();
  };

  $toggle.click(onToggleClick);
  
  updateView();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="raven-sortable">Raven sortable</button>

<button id="deknop"></button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would not work since im constrained in changing anything in the HTML. Thanks for taking the time. Much appreciated Krzysztof!

Comment: I didn't change anything in HTML. I'm taking only about JS :)